# Qt how to get application to get md5 checksum of itself

Tags: c++, qt, md5, checksum

Working on a Qt application. I'm trying to get the exe file to return an md5 checksum of itself while it's running. How can I do this?

I tried this:

```
QFile theFile("file.exe");
QByteArray thisFile;
if (theFile.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly))
{
    thisFile = theFile.readAll();
}
else
{
    qDebug() << "Can't open";
}

qDebug() << QString("%1").arg(thisFile.length());

fileMd5 = QString(QCryptographicHash::hash((thisFile), QCryptographicHash::Md5).toHex().toUpper());

qDebug() << fileMd5;
```

This does not return the correct value, however.

Update:

I got it working with other files. The problem seems to be that I am unable to read the exe while it's running.

Final update:

This is the solution:

```
QFile theFile(QCoreApplication::applicationFilePath());
QByteArray thisFile;
if (theFile.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly))
{
    thisFile = theFile.readAll();
}
else
{
    qDebug() << "Can't open file.";
}

QString fileMd5 = QString(QCryptographicHash::hash((thisFile), QCryptographicHash::Md5).toHex());

qDebug() << fileMd5;
```

Comment: you have to make a copy of it but I don't now how... Why is it for?

Comment: This will be for checking versions. Instead of checking a version number, I want my application to get an md5 checksum of itself and compare that to a PHP script that will return another md5 checksum of the latest version. If they don't match, a link will be shown to the user to download the latest version.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to call `open` on `theFile`.

```
if (!theFile.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly))
    // Handle error here
```

Also, you should be using `QCoreApplication::applicationFilePath()` to get the path to the executable.

Comment: I just figured that out. The problem now is it can't seem to open a file that is in use.

Comment: QCoreApplication::applicationFilePath() <== This is what I needed. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You have to create an independent application (let's call it `myApp`) which check the MD5sum and compare it with your PHP script and ask for an update if needed or load directly the application.

Like so : `myApp`=> need update ? (update) : (`TheRealApp`)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, looks like it just wasn't finding the file. I tried an absolute path instead of a relative and it worked. I'll have to figure out what's going wrong, but it looks like it can read itself while running.

Comment: Something was weird with the build. I rebuilt it command line instead of in QtCreator and now the relative path works. It can read itself the way I wanted by using "file.exe" as the path.

Comment: It's because there is a difference between applicationFilePath and relatives